# injecting custom Dialogs into an existing WiX Dialog Set

Tags: dialog, wix

This is the first time that I have to customize the UI of an installer, so I am quite new to this.

I want to place a custom dialog between LicenseAgreementDlg and SetupTypeDlg of the WixUI_Mondo Dialog Set.
The custom dialog doesn't show up during the installation and I am not sure why.

The dialog is located in the file DbDialogs.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="DatabaseInformationDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProdictName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
                [...]
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Back">
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish> 
                </Control>

                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Next">
                    [...]
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                [...]
            </Dialog>

            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="DatabaseInformationDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="DatabaseInformationDlg">1</Publish>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The Product references the WixUI_Mondo Dialog Set, to create the basic dialog order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" [...] />
        [...]
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
        [...]
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

What is wrong/missing?

Comment: Move the `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />` parallel to the `UI` element. I do similar things and in my fragment, I place the `UIRef` under the `UI` and the overrides take affect. Additionally, you need to define the `@Order` attribute on your `Publish` elements that override the button sequences which you are redefining.

Comment: @Ritmo2k I've done like you said. Now it works for the Back-Control of `SetupTypeDlg`, but **not** for the Next-Control of `LicenseAgreementDlg`.

Comment: Try different values for `@Order`. Despite reading the documentation, my experience is working values don't always make obvious sense to me. I am sure I misunderstand the semantics of the attributes documentation.

Comment: It did not work with `Order="1"` for `LicenseAgreementDlg` and `Order=2` for `SetupTypeDlg`, but now it works the other way around. Thanks for your help.